# Program will not uninstall

Tags: apt, snap, uninstall, john-the-ripper

I have john the ripper installed on my ubuntu 20.04 machine.
Originally, I simply installed it using `apt-get`.

But now I need to remove it from my machine. Currently when I type `john` I get this:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/TA/AppliedInfoSec/PassCracking$ john
John the Ripper 1.9.0-jumbo-1 OMP [linux-gnu 64-bit x86_64 AVX2 AC]
Copyright (c) 1996-2019 by Solar Designer and others
Homepage: http://www.openwall.com/john/
```

and this is the location:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/TA/AppliedInfoSec/PassCracking$ whereis john
john: /snap/bin/john
```

First i try:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/TA/AppliedInfoSec/PassCracking$ sudo apt-get remove john
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'john' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

'
But this has no effect, john is still on my system.
and then `ask@Garsy:~/Notes/TA/AppliedInfoSec/PassCracking$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove john` which has the same effect.

I also try `sudo apt-get purge john` with no effect.

I don't really know what to do, I can't seem to find any info about uninstalling john other than the stuff i have already tried.

Comment: It is a snap and not with apt installed

Answer (score 0):

The path of the executable is `/snap/bin/john`, therefore John the Ripper has been installed as a [snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)), not via `apt-get`.

To remove the package (or, more precisely, the snap) you must run

```
sudo snap remove john
```